# How to implement NIO with SSL in java?

Tags: java, ssl, nio

I want to implement SSL over my Java application using NIO. Have searched internet for same but not able to proceed. Sample implementation code would be a great help.

Comment: Your question is unclear: Do you want to implement the SSL protocol yourself, or do you want to pipe data across an SSL-protected tunnel?

Comment: First hit on Google for "nio ssl": http://onjava.com/onjava/2004/11/03/ssl-nio.html Did you really search "the Internet"?

Comment: there is a lot of stuff on google. For example http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/index.html#NIO and SSL on 1.4

Comment: How about jboss netty? Check http://www.jboss.org/netty

Answer (score 2):

With the SSLEngine, but be warned it's no joke. There is some sample code in the JDK but it makes some rather untenable assumptions, such as only one handshake per connection, client mode only, etc. Integration with a Selector is particularly problematic.

Answer (score 1):

SSLEngine is the standard way of doing SSL/TLS with NIO in Java.

But it is *seriously* hard to use, and not recommended for applications that just want a secure socket.

There is fortunately at least one library alternative: [TLS Channel](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel) wraps a SSLContext (or SSLEngine) and exposing a ByteChannel interface, doing the heavy lifting internally.

(Disclaimer: I am the library's main author)

Answer (score 0):

Like Friek said, look at netty from Jboss. 
In their [documentation section](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation) there is an example involving SSL.